# How to go through a Gson object, with multiple levels Arrays

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to get the parameters inside **jSon** `items>item>image>images>transparent` using the **Gson** library. The idea is to capture `transparent`, `transparent_blank` and `transparent_dark`. But I don't know how I can get these values, for the moment I have created the following:

**Json**

```
{ 
  "date_layout":"day-month-year",
  "lastupdate":1547596830,
    "items":[{
      "name":"Cleans Cuts",
      "featured":"true",
      "item":{
        "image":"http:www.domain.com/unwanted_image.jpg",
           "images":{
              "transparent":"http:www.domain.com/desired_image1.jpg",
              "transparent_blank":"http:www.domain.com/desired_image2.jpg",
              "transparent_dark":"http:www.domain.com/desired_image3.jpg"
             }
          }
    },
    {
      "name":"Cleans Cuts",
      "featured":"true",
      "item":{
        "image":"http:www.domain.com/unwanted_image.jpg",
           "images":{
              "transparent":"http:www.domain.com/desired_image1.jpg",
              "transparent_blank":"http:www.domain.com/desired_image2.jpg",
              "transparent_dark":"http:www.domain.com/desired_image3.jpg"
             }
          }
    }]
}
```

**.MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

String url = "http://www.example.com/file.json";

Request request = new Request.Builder()
       .url(url)
       .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
       if(response.isSuccessful()){
          String response_jSon = response.body().string();
          Gson gson = new Gson();
          Datos datosFinal = gson.fromJson(response_jSon, Datos.class);
              for (int i=0; i<datosFinal.items.size(); i++){
                Log.d("msg_2", datosFinal.items.get(i).name);
              }
}
```

And I'm only able to get to items as you can see in the .MainActivity Log.

Class Objects for the Json

**Datos.java**

```
public class Datos {
    public String date_layout;
    public Int lastupdate;
     List<items> items;
}
```

**items.java**

```
public class items {
    public String name;
}
```

Comment: auto generate Plain Old Java Objects using
 https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit#automated-approach---auto-generating-the-java-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json is not very clean, I would suggest that you rework how this json string is generated, but if you still want to achieve getting those values without reworking the json, you need to change your **Items** class to :

```
`public class items {
    public String name;
    public String featured;
    public Item item;
}`
```

Then you need to create another class called **Item**

```
`public class Item{
    public String image;
    public Image images;
}`
```

You will also need to create an **Image** class, like so:

```
`public class Image {
    public String transparent;
    public String transparent_blank;
    public String transparent_dark;
}`
```

Then you can log these values in your loop:

```
`Datos datosFinal = gson.fromJson(response_jSon, Datos.class);
 for (int i=0; i<datosFinal.items.size(); i++){
        Log.d("msg_2", datosFinal.items.get(i).item.images.transparent);
        Log.d("msg_2", datosFinal.items.get(i).item.images.transparent_blank);
        Log.d("msg_2", datosFinal.items.get(i).item.images.transparent_dark);
}`
```

While this may work, I would highly suggest you to rework your json and make it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the following class also to getting value for transparent, transparent_blank and transparent_dark

Images.java
Item.java

Replace this class:

```
public class Items{

private Item item;

private String name;

private String featured;

public Item getItem ()
{
    return item;
}

public void setItem (Item item)
{
    this.item = item;
}

public String getName ()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName (String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getFeatured ()
{
    return featured;
}

public void setFeatured (String featured)
{
    this.featured = featured;
}


}
```

Add this class:

```
public class Images{

private String transparent_blank;

private String transparent_dark;

private String transparent;

public String getTransparent_blank ()
{
    return transparent_blank;
}

public void setTransparent_blank (String transparent_blank)
{
    this.transparent_blank = transparent_blank;
}

public String getTransparent_dark ()
{
    return transparent_dark;
}

public void setTransparent_dark (String transparent_dark)
{
    this.transparent_dark = transparent_dark;
}

public String getTransparent ()
{
    return transparent;
}

public void setTransparent (String transparent)
{
    this.transparent = transparent;
}
```

}

Also, Add this Class:

```
public class Item {

private Images images;

private String image;

public Images getImages ()
{
    return images;
}

public void setImages (Images images)
{
    this.images = images;
}

public String getImage ()
{
    return image;
}

public void setImage (String image)
{
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

Now, you will get the value using the getter method.

Answer (score 1):

you must use

```
public class items {
    public String name;
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    public String featured;
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    public item mItem;
}

public class item {
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    public String image;
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    public images mImages;
}

public class images {
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    public String transparent;
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    public String transparent_blank;
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    public String transparent_dark;
}
```

you can genetate pojo by using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/